# У меня ломается приложение, после обфускации

Tags: android

У меня приложение с Custom Tabs и оно работает некорректно, если я включаю обфускацию с помощью Pro Guard. С чем это может быть связанно?

```
2021-06-02 11:18:32.618 10953-10953/com.example.test4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test4, PID: 10953
java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:496)
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:486)
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:458)
    at com.phanterheights.darkwinner.ChromeTabPage.ui.ChromeTabFragment.createChromeTab(:36)
    at com.phanterheights.darkwinner.ChromeTabPage.ui.ChromeTabFragment.onCreateView(:23)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.F0(:2698)
    at c.m.b.r.e(:320)
    at c.m.b.m.A0(:1187)
    at c.m.b.m.a(:2224)
    at c.m.b.m.T(:1997)
    at c.m.b.m.M0(:1953)
    at c.m.b.m.Q(:1849)
    at c.m.b.m$d.run(:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

> Сам фрагмент с Custom Tabs:

```
    class ChromeTabFragment : Fragment() {
    private val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
    private val customTabsIntent = builder.build()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val url = arguments?.getString("location")
        createChromeTab(url)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chrome_tab, container, false)
    }
    
    @Keep
    private fun createChromeTab(data: String?) {
        val packageName = "com.android.chrome"
        customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(packageName)
        customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        context?.let { customTabsIntent.launchUrl(it, Uri.parse(data)) }
    }


    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        activity?.finish()
    }
}
```

Без обфускации приложение работает корректно. С чем это может быть связано?

UPD: Добавил файл

> proguard-rules

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш proguard-rules файл. Он находится во вкладке Gradle Scripts или если смотреть на директории то project/app/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: @VladOrlinskas Добавил, спасибо за правку.

Comment: попробуйте вот такой, здесь конечно много лишнего https://gist.github.com/jemshit/767ab25a9670eb0083bafa65f8d786bb  И не забудьте применить данную кофигурациию: в вашем build.gradle (app) есть блок buildTypes, скорее всего там есть блок release в нем добавьте строку `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` Это там где вы включаете minifyEnabled true. Если не понятно, можете прикрепить ваш build.gradle (app)

Comment: @VladOrlinskas у меня есть эта строка, к сожалению она никак не помогла)

Comment: proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt")),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )

Comment: @VladOrlinskas proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' - то, что вы предложили build.gradle не принял. Но все равно спасибо за старания)

Comment: Если вы уверены, что проблема в обфускации вам необходимо найти проблемную библиотеку/класс и игнорировать его в proguard файле. С помощью keep.

Comment: @VladOrlinskas Воот, это я и хотел услышать. Спасибо! Да, уверен на 100%, что проблема в обфускации, поскольку без нее приложение работает корректно.